# vSphere Web login not working / root looking possible

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have a little problem with a vSphere Server and I hope you guys could help me. When I tried to login as root on the server directly with keyboard, mouse and display it is working. But when I tried to login over the web:

https://192.168.1.1

with the same login data I always get the message that the login data are not correct.
My problem is that my predecessor has setup this system, and he didn't knows the passwords any more. I am a beginner in vSphere but now we want to backup and reconfigure the virtual machine. How can I do this directly on the server or does I need the access to the web to do all this stuff?
Thanks

Comment: Some more specific information could be useful. Where exactly are you trying to log in (vSphere is a suite of products, it is unclear if you try to log into vCenter, which could be an appliance or installed on a server, or an ESXi host). Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to log in directly onto an ESXi host. I've experienced a couple of times that perfectly valid credentials (that worked via SSH or on the local console) did not work on the web interface.

This was easily resolvable by restarting the management services on that host. To do that you only need to log on to the local console and navigate to *Troubleshooting Options*:

[image]

Then *Restart Management Agents*

[image]

Afterwards the credentials should work again in the web interface.

Comment: Thanks for that. I restart the complete server once before. But this didn't helped much. I tried to login direct into the webinterface from the host. The IP from the host is 192.168.1.1. I enter this address in the browser and try to login. it looks like this: https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2016/11_w48/1129091/Locked_-000271.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing account lockout issue, as in too many failed logins have temporarily disabled access  to the account.

Once you login over ssh/console check `hostd.log` and `authd.log` for login issues, that would help you diagnose it deeper.

You can try to create a second user with proper permissions using vicfg-user on the esxi host.

Docs are here: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vcli/vcli41/doc/reference/vicfg-user.html